# Cambiar color del borde de un pikerInput en Rshiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

buen día

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación con Rshiny y le he hecho varios arreglos con CSS. Ahora lo que intento es quitar un color azul que tiene in Input numérico como el que muestro:

[image: Input]

Usé el siguiente código para intentar cambiar el color pero no funciona

```
.form-control:onclick {
                         background-color: #F3E9AF;
                         border-color: #E9C80B;
                         box-shadow: 10px 16px 15px #E9C80B;
            }
```

Gracias  por su ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, podría tener el código de una shinyapp de ejemplo para que otros pueden reproducir tu problema. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar la pseudo clase `:focus` en lugar de `:onclick`

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
        .form-control:focus  {
                         background-color: #F3E9AF;
                         border-color: #E9C80B;
                         box-shadow: 10px 16px 15px #E9C80B;
            }
        ")))
```

Enseguida te dejo el código completo de una `shinyapp` que hace esto.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

   tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
        .form-control:focus  {
                         background-color: #F3E9AF;
                         border-color: #E9C80B;
                         box-shadow: 10px 16px 15px #E9C80B;
            }
        "))),

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Calculo"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         numericInput("num", "Numero:", 1, min = 1, max = 100),
         actionButton('btnCalculo', 'Calcular',
                      btn_type = "button", type = "primary"),
    ),
      mainPanel(
         uiOutput("valuebox2")#valueBoxOutput("valuebox2") 
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

    rv<-reactiveValues(result=NULL)

    observeEvent(input$btnCalculo,{
        rv$result[input$btnCalculo] <- input$num + 1000
    })

    output$valuebox2<-renderUI({#renderInfoBox({
        if(is.null(rv$result)){
            div()
        }else(
            #valueBox(format(round(rv$result,0), big.mark = ","),"Suma")
            lapply(rev(rv$result), function(i) { 
                valueBox(format(round(i,0), big.mark = ","),"Suma")
            } )
        )
    })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```